# Android: Show spinner at actionbar with fixed title

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-spinner

I would like to have a spinner in the action bar showing the title `Options` **always**, no matter which one has been selected.

At the moment the upper box shows the choosed option as soon as it is selected.

How could I achive that ?

[image]

this is my code

```
        MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.actionbar_nextevents);
        if (menuItem!=null){
            Spinner spinner = (Spinner) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menuItem);
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            list.add("Option 1");
            list.add("Option 2");
            list.add("Option 3");
            spinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.listitem_nextevents, R.id.option, list));
        }
```

Comment: Override onSpinnerItemSelected. On item selection, set the title of Spinner to be "Option"

Comment: So what happened with above code?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tries this :

```
    MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.actionbar_nextevents);
if (menuItem != null) {
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menuItem);
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("Options ");
    list.add("Option 1");
    list.add("Option 2");
    list.add("Option 3");
    spinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.listitem_nextevents, R.id.option, list));
    spinner.setSelection(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code

open menu.xml and paste below code

```
<item
        android:title="select city"
        android:id="@+id/my_menu_spinner"
        yourapp:actionViewClass="android.widget.Spinner"
        yourapp:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
```

in your activity class override onCreateOptionMenu() method and write below code

```
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        spinner = (Spinner) menu.findItem(R.id.my_menu_spinner)
                .getActionView(); // find the spinner
            citieslist.add(cityName);
        }

        ArrayAdapter mSpinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this.getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext(),                         R.layout.spinner_item, citieslist);
        mSpinnerAdapter
                .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(mSpinnerAdapter);
return true
```

}

create file spinne_item.xml in layouts and paste below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColor="#455560" />
```

Comment: did you even try running this code? you use a variable in its' own initializer statement, before it even exists. -1. moreover, when I run this code, `MenuItem.getActionView()` throws NullPointerException.

Answer (score 0):

Late reply for those who are still struggling!

The first option of your spinner should be your title!
then when your are handling every option simply put this line at the end.`spinner.setSelection(0);`
This keeps the title the first option every time an option is selected

example:

```
switch (position) {
                case 0:
                   //my other methods and...

                    spinner.setSelection(0);
                    break;

                case 1:
                    //my other methods and...

                    spinner.setSelection(0);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    //my other methods and...

                    spinner.setSelection(0);
                    break;
```